# Running a tensorflow model in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a simple iris classifier in an Android app. I created a MLP in keras, converted it into .pb format and put it into an assets folder. The keras model:

```
data = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
x=data.data
y=data.target
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)



x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25)


inputs=Input(shape=(4,))
x=Dense(10,activation="relu",name="input_layer")(inputs)
x=Dense(10,activation="relu")(x)
x=Dense(15,activation="relu")(x)
x=Dense(3,activation="softmax",name="output_layer")(x)

model=Model(inputs,x)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.05, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0001, nesterov=False)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",  metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=20, epochs=100, verbose=0)
```

The code in AndroidStudio(I have 4 fields for input numbers,1 output field and 1 Button. The predictClick method gets called when the button gets clicked):

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
}

String model_name ="file:///android_asset/iris_model.pb";
String output_name = "output_layer";
String input_name = "input_data";
TensorFlowInferenceInterface tfinterface;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tfinterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(),model_name);

}




public void predictClick(View v){
    TextView antwort = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.antwort);
    EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
    EditText number3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number3);
    EditText number4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number4);
    Button predict = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    float[] result = {};




    String zahl1 = number1.getText().toString();
    String zahl2 = number2.getText().toString();
    String zahl3 = number3.getText().toString();
    String zahl4 = number4.getText().toString();
    float n1 = Float.parseFloat(zahl1);
    float n2 = Float.parseFloat(zahl2);
    float n3 = Float.parseFloat(zahl3);
    float n4 = Float.parseFloat(zahl4);


    float[] inputs={n1,n2,n3,n4};


    //im pretty sure these lines cause the error
    tfinterface.feed(input_name,inputs,4,1);
    tfinterface.run(new String[]{output_name});
    tfinterface.fetch(output_name,result);



    antwort.setText(Float.toString(result[0]));




}
```

The build runs without error, but when I hit the predict button the app chrashes. When I leave the the lines

```
tfinterface.feed(input_name,inputs,4,1);
tfinterface.run(new String[]{output_name});
tfinterface.fetch(output_name,result);
```

out the app runs correctly, so I think that's were the error comes from.

Comment: Please, find and include exception from LogCat related to that crash. Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Keep in mind, your code isn't running "in Android Studio". That's just a text editor that builds your code. The code runs on an actual Android device

Answer (score 0):

Your model's input layer is named "input_layer" in the python code, but "input_data" in the Java code.

Also check your logcat output. You should get an error message stating, that the model doesn't have the input layer you're searching for.